# Confusing issue between string pointer and a character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

Dear Stack overflow community

I am learning C and C++, and I have some questions related to String pointers and Character arrays .

I have done a simple program:

```
void Strings (void)
{
    char String1  [20];

    cout<<"Please Enter your String1: "<<endl;

    cin>>String1;
    cin.ignore ();


    cout<<String1<<endl;
}
```

- Created `String1 [20]`, character array of 20 elements
- cout<<"Please enter your string1"
- `cin>>String1;` String1 acts as a pointer to the array, what ever I type it will be stored in String1,
- Typed "ThisisaniceexampleofstringsinCpp" (34 characters)
- I compiled the program, and it crashed because the string I entered is more than 20 characters (makes sense).

I made the following changes to the program.

```
void Strings (void)
{
    char*String0 = new char[20];

    cout<<"Please Enter your String0: "<<endl;

    cin>>String0;
    cin.ignore ();


    cout<<String0<<endl;
}
```

- I create a character pointer that points to an address in program memory of a space of 20 character element (like a character array of 20 elements
- Cout "Please enter your string"
- What ever string I type it will be stored in String0 (address pointer that points to a character array of 20 elements
- I type in "ThisisaniceexampleofstringsinCpp" (34 characters) and it got stored  in String0 with no problems.

Why is it that `char*String0 = new char[20]` a character pointer with space of 20 character element can store the 34 character string, but `char String1 [20]` a character array of 20 elements can't store. shouldn't I get an error with both examples, as the string I entered is more than the space they hold/point to?

Thank you in advance.

Adam

Comment: Writing past the boundary of a buffer is undefined behavior. By the virtue of being undefined, it can work or crash, or make volcanoes erupt. Better avoid it than ponder when it can work.

Comment: It is [basically this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why).

Comment: Appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. It's still undefined. Of course, the real solution would be to scrap the [tag:c] tag, and use `std::string` instead of raw pointers or arrays.

Comment: @StoryTeller @juanchopanza
yes, I read about Undefined Behaviour, in the other post, I understand a bit now why it "Works".

About `std::string` I am still learning C++ and haven't covered it, I will in the future.